# Where do Data in /Out, Write Enable, and Read Enable Wires connect to in RAM?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

This is a screenshot of the Crash Course Video Registers and RAM #6. From YouTube, here's the link "[Crash Course Video](https://youtu.be/fpnE6UAfbtU?si=vtowKNenK0NpQ0Hh)". It's talking about using Gated latches to store memory, and putting it in a 16 x 16 grid of sorts, activating the wire to select the specific area where you want to get data from.

How does the Data in/out, Write Enable, and Read Enable wire work?/Get input/Turn on from they put a ... around those wire but where does it go? Connect to? Activate?

[image: screenshot]

<sub>Screenshot from: [YouTube - CrashCourse - "Registers and RAM: Crash Course Computer Science #6"](https://youtu.be/fpnE6UAfbtU?si=vtowKNenK0NpQ0Hh)</sub>

Comment: These are control signals and are serving as *input* to the RAM component. They are driven by some external control logic (CPU).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. 6264 Pinout. Image source: [Circuits DIY](https://www.circuits-diy.com/6264-8kx8-120ns-cmos-ram-datasheet/).*

The **data in/out** in this chip are I/O<sub>0</sub> to I/O<sub>7</sub> indicated at (1) and (3).

**Write Enable** is shown as (3) in the image. The bar over it indicates that it is inverted and must be pulled low to enable a write of data from the I/O to the byte address selected by A<sub>0</sub> to A<sub>12</sub>. WE is common to the whole address space.

**Read Enable** is just generated internally by an invertor operating on the WE input.

Since there are eight I/O lines we can tell that the memory is 8-bits wide.

Since there are 13 address lines we can tell that there are 2<sup>13</sup> = 8K (= 64 kilobits) of RAM.

Comment: "*Since there are 13 address lines we can tell …*" - could some of these be ignored? Like maybe for a smaller (cheaper) but pin-compatible memory module?

Comment: @Bergi: Sure, the user could ignore them and tie, say, A12 to GND if they only needed 4K of RAM. The other trick is that the manufacturer tries to make all the chips 8K, tests them and if a defect is found in one half of the chip then they leave internally bond one pin high or low to sell as a 4K chip with one less address line, more faults, a 2K chip, 1K chip, etc. At some point it makes sense to use the next size down standard package.

Answer (score 2):

These are "global" signals. They're connected to every single bit cell in the array, and also to input/output terminals of the circuit.

So when the user asserts one of these signals for the circuit, it's asserted for every single cell in the circuit. Or when one of the cells applies a signal to the DATA OUT, it appears on the DATA OUT terminal of the circuit (and it would be very bad for more than one cell to try to drive DATA OUT at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

> How does the Data in/out, Write Enable, and Read Enable wire work?

They get turned on and off from a memory controller either on the same IC or external.